# How {% block main_content %} works in django crudbuilder

Tags: python, django, block, crud

I'm using a django app called crudbuilder with the purpose of building a table that can be manipulated with multiple filter inputs, as well as being able to toggle the categories within the table on and off.

The github for crudbuilder is here https://github.com/asifpy/django-crudbuilder/blob/master/crudbuilder/templates/base.html#L54 & I have marked the specific line of their code that is giving me trouble. `{% block main_content %}{% endblock %}` is the line that's giving me some trouble.  "main_content" refers to a table, a search bar, a title, a "create button" & a pagination.

I want to be able to manipulate the table depending on custom search inputs that I've implemented into the UI. I can get results to come up but they completely erase the "main_content" block. I want to be able make it so that my custom search box can filter through the table, I'm just having a hard time figuring out how it works in the crudbuilder git hub code.

Within the crudbuilder code, that main_content block contains a search bar that does exactly what I want. but I can't figure out how they are making in work.

Their search bar will filter the names on the database but that's it. I have other elements I'd like to filter as well. Figuring out how their search bar works would be a huge help.

If anybody has the time to help me out and explain to me how the "block" is working in the code, that would be amazing. Thank you so much.

Let me know if you need to see any of my code, but any explanation on how the `{% block main_content %}{% endblock %}` works would be a huge help.

Comment: Every other template in the app will `{% extends "base.html" %}` so within all their template files all they have to do is create blocks of content, for example they create a `{% block main_content %}`, this saves them repeating the same base template many times. In the base.html file the `{% block main_content %}{% endblock %}` is used to tell the template system where it should insert the `main_content` block into that template.

A good place to ask an app specific question could be on their issues page https://github.com/asifpy/django-crudbuilder/issues

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have a much better understanding now.  If you make this an answer, I'll approve it.